# Task ownership in microservices architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices

In my system tasks are stored in a central place. The services will pick a task they can handle and execute them. Multiple instances of same service are run to handle the demand.

Now the question is how to make sure that a task is executed by only one instance of a service. Is there a common or widely used pattern to do this in microservices architecture?

Comment: When you say central place, you mean something like a data store?

Comment: Yes, shared database/datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below:

1.Create a Wrapper for the tasks meaning create a Task Queue and may be you can also create a service around it.

2.Now when a instance of a particular Micro Service picks up a Task from the Task Queue, Pop that task out from the Queue.In that way you ensure that only 1 instance of a particular Micro Service services that task.